# Can you allow ASCII-only and Unicode answers in the one challenge?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that is intended to allow Unicode input. No-one has posted an answer yet but someone has asked if it can be ASCII input only. That could drastically change which languages were competitive. Can I have the same challenge but score ASCII-only against ASCII-only and Unicode against Unicode? I.e. make them non-competitive against the other type, only with their own type?

Comment: I'm not sure what ASCII-only and Unicode refer to here. Do you mean source code? Input? Output?

Comment: ... ASCII vs Unicode source code answer should be the same?? I think the commenter wants a only non-golfing lang question, and unicode isn't the problem.

Comment: Not really. The commenter is saying that unicode will disadvantage golflangs.

Comment: @KennyLau ... why?  Most languages, golfing or not, allow unicode???

Comment: Well, then why did he mention `\X`?

Comment: So the commenter was misdirected all along...?

Comment: Related: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9054/31716

Answer (score 3):

## Allow more than one category of competition in a single challenge

The general consensus on CGCC seems to be that limiting a challenge to a subset of languages is bad. So a language such as GolfScript, which has no built-in UTF-8 support, should not be forbidden from taking part in challenges [such as this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194869/do-you-make-me-up).

On the other hand, an answer that can only handle ASCII shouldn't be considered to be directly competing against answers that handle full UTF-8, UTF-16, or UCS-4/UTF-32. Allowing more than one category of competition is a really good solution to this dilemma.

For that matter, another type of split competition that should be allowed is Arbitrary-precision answers vs. Floating-point/Limited-precision answers, but that's a topic for a another Meta post.

Answer (score 0):

## Well, no.

By holding two different competitions in one challenge, your challenge becomes unclear, as all questions require one specific scoring system that leads to one specific winner.